# ASP.Net C# - Redirect to a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, redirect, response.redirect

I've got a 'menu' within a Master page which includes a number of image buttons with click events.

Within each click event, I want to redirect the user to a specific (Child) page.  However, if the user is already on the correct (Child) page, I don't want to refresh the page and lose the entered data.

In the example below, I want to redirect the user to browse.aspx however, if the user is already on browse.aspx, I don't want to refresh it.

Is there a better way to do this than the following?

```
protected void ibtnBrowse_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Request.Url.Segments[1].ToString().Equals("browse.aspx"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/browse.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the absolute url look like? If it's just `http://example.com/browse.aspx`, you can check `Request.Url.Path`.

Comment: Quiz question: if I have BroWse.AsPx open will it still work as if browse.aspx?

Comment: Your button click events result in POSTs, so unless you do your check on the client side and don't do the POST if it meets your criteria, you won't be able to prevent at least a refresh of the current page.

Answer (score 1):

How about disabling the Image button on the page?

e.g.

When you are on browse.aspx, in code behind browse.aspx.cs you can disable the button.

```
ImageButton iBtn = (ImageButton)Page.Master.FindControl("ibtnBrowse");
iBtn.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

By having server side click events the page will always "refresh" when clicking on these buttons. However, if you are simply looking to avoid doing an unnecessary redirect in your code you can use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
```

If you decide to use javascript to switch between pages you can use location:

```
location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
location.assign("http://www.w3schools.com");
```